Self signed certificate doesn't apply
I have a site https://example.com. I want to add certificate when particular port is called like https://exampme.com:5000. What I do is this:
    var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/certificates/example_com.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/certificates/exmaple_com.crt')
    };
    var httpsServer = https.createServer(options,function (req, res) {
       res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    ....
}).listen(5000)

The error I get is ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when I try to hit the https://example.com:5000 through the browser and another one - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the network tab when doing it through ajax request. Not sure why they are different.
Certificates are created with OpenSSL 1.1.1
